# CoreData Relationship not updating after insert using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, magicalrecord

I have a app with two views. The first permits to create a number of entities in Core Data and the second one, to display data of the created entities.

In my CoreData data models, I have two entities:

`CD_AProduct` and `CD_AProductItems`.

`CD_AProduct` contains an optional relationship named productItems witch are `CD_AProductItems`:

[image]

`CD_AProductItems` contains a non-optional relationship named product witch is `CD_AProduct`

[image]

In the `AppDelegate` class I instantiate the Core Data Stack like this:

```
MagicalRecord.setupAutoMigratingCoreDataStack()
```

---

**The code of the first view**

Then in my code, I create a first time four CD_AProductItems and link the relationships:

```
if let entity = CD_ProductItem.MR_createEntity() as? CD_ProductItem
{
    product.addProductItemsObject(entity)

    entity.product = product

    success()
}
else
{
    failure()
}
```

Then, I save the entities in the persistent store:

```
NSManagedObjectContext.MR_defaultContext().MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion({(successBlock : Bool, error : NSError!) in

        if successBlock
        {
            success()
        }
        else
        {                            
            if error != nil
            {
                failure()
            }
            else
            {
                success()
            }
        }
    }
)
```

---

**The code of the second view**

```
// Product is retrieved with CD_AProduct.MR_findFirstByAttribute
for productItem in product.productItems
{
    println("productItem: \(productItem)")   
}
```

---

Now what's wrong with this.

- First view: The user "choose" 4 product items to add into the product.
- Click on the top-right button of my view to go to the next view.
- Second view: Display the data of the 4 product items created.
- Go back to the first page using the top-left button of my view.
- First view: Add 4 more product items into my product
- Go the the next page
- Second view: Display only 4 product items instead of 8 !

I think this problem come from the Core Data Stack that is not updated when I go to the second view (the one which display the data of the selected product items).

Any suggestions on what happen and how can I be sure that the entire Core Data Stack has been updated before to go to the second view ?

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you need different elements in different `indexPath` so in this case you should give the indexPath to be found before you go to the next viewController. At this moment you are loading all items which contains `product.productItems`. Because of here is little code in your post lets imagine you have UITableView as first Controller.

First of all you will ned to create an array which will store CD_AProduct elements:

```
var productArrays = [CD_AProduct]!
```

You have save function so we will skip this step here.

Then just create simple prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
   if (segue.identifier == "GoToDetailView") {
      let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! CD_AProductItemsView
      let CD_AProduct = productArrays[tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!.row]
      vc.CD_AProductDetailView = CD_AProduct
      vc.CD_AProductItemsDetailView = productArrays.detailEntities.allObjects as! Array
  }
}
```

P.S in the last line detailEntities means the NSSet in your managed object list. You should change this.

Now if you run your app it will crash because `tableView.indexPath` at this moment will be nil because no one has give this information to the prepareForSegue. So to fix this problem we should use our `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` :

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GoToDetailView", sender: self)
```

We are Done! Its very late answer of course but maybe it will help someone.